# How can I add 100 amp electrical service to a shop?

Tags: electrical, wiring, installation, workshop, subpanel

I am going to wire my shop and want ot run #2 copper to a 100amp breaker panel. I really do not have the space in the 200 amp panel in the house, my question - is there a way to pull this wire off the service entrance straight to the shop, and does that require another meter base or what?

Comment: If you want to get additional service for your shop, you'll have to contact your electric supplier.

Comment: If you contact your utility, they may be able to install a double lug meter socket.  This would allow you to feed both your house, and shop with a single meter.  This work can only be completed by a licensed electrician.

Answer (score 10):

reasons going to the service entrance will be difficult:

- you'll have to open the meter box, and most meter boxes are tamper sealed by the electric company so you will have to involve them.
- the meter box lugs are probably not sized for multiple connections.
- this creates a potentially dangerous wiring setup. someone may assume that the main panel in the house covers the entire house.

i would go with connecting a subpanel to your main panel. i assume that the existing circuits in the shop go to the main panel? take them out and use the space you just freed up to wire in your subpanel.